# Get the nearly equal point (a kind of IndexOfPoint method)

Tags: javascript, three.js

With three.js I need to get the mesh point wich is nearly equal (within a 'fuzz') to a calculated point. This calculated point is not a THREE.Vector2/3, it's a generic object with x y properties.
The function/method is used by a recursive function and a 'real time' process, that's why it has to be optimized.

The simplest expression I've found is the following. Let's say that it's a 2D point, that I provide an array (geometry.vertices), and there is no need to compute the distance :

```
function IndexOfPoint ( pt, lst ) {
    var i = -1;
    var test = lst.some( function ( p ) {
        i++;
        return ( Math.abs( p.x - pt.x ) < 1E-12 ) && ( Math.abs( p.y - pt.y ) < 1E-12 );
    });
    return test? i: -1;
}
```

It works, but I have made this quickly and would like to know if there is a best and fastest method ... (please no additional library for that, only plain js)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks good for me. You could probably skip the increment on the index var i, since the current index is already provided to the callback as the 2nd argument as in Array.prototype.some( function(element, index, array) { ... } ):

```
function IndexOfPoint ( pt, lst ) {
    var i = -1;
    lst.some( function ( p, idx ) {
        if ( ( Math.abs( p.x - pt.x ) < 1E-12 ) && ( Math.abs( p.y - pt.y ) < 1E-12 ) ) {
            i = idx;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with three.js, but if the list is sorted and if the grid is uniform, you might be able to obtain the index of the closest vector immediately and simply test that index. For example:

```
function IndexOfPoint (pt, list) {
    // assuming the list of points is sorted going from left to right, top to bottom
    var index = Math.floor((pt.x - offsetX) * scaleX) + gridWidth * Math.floor((pt.y - offsetY) * scaleY);

    var candidatePoint = list[index];

    if (candidatePoint && (Math.abs(pt.x - candidatePoint.x) < 1E-12) && (Math.abs(pt.y - candidatePoint.y) < 1E-12) {
      return index;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
}
```